# How to get current time in different versions of EOSIO

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, eosiocpp, eosio-cpp

Depending on which version of EOSIO you use, there are different options available for finding the current time. What are they?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Until `eosio.cdt v1.6`

You could use:

- `eosio::current_time()`
- `now()`

## From eosio.cdt v1.6 onwards

You have to `#include <eosio/system.hpp>` and then you can use:

- `eosio::current_time_point`
- `eosio::current_block_time`

Comment: Where was this change mentioned, I don't see it in any release notes.

Comment: I don't think they mentioned it directly. It was just something you had to find out for yourself. That is why I made a question and answered it, anticipating people having this problem.

Comment: thank you.  I wish they would bloody document stuff like this so poor sods like me don't spend all kinds of hours trying to figure out why something doesn't work.  question: I see in the 1.6.1 version of the CDT, that `now()` is still defined: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/master/libraries/eosiolib/system.h however, if I `#include <eosio/system.hpp>` I still get the error "use of undeclared identifier 'now'; did you mean 'new'?" -- why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: and if I look in libraries/eosiolib/system.hpp, I don't see either current_time_point or current_block_time (I need to know the return types)... how does this work? I see that including from eosiolib is deprecated and we must include from eosio, but I don't see any such directory!

Comment: and what the hell was wrong with providing `now()` anyway?? I'm so aggravated

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/532

Answer (score 0):

In older version we can only get the current block time with publish_time(). But now its available also in eosio::current_time_point
eosio::current_block_time. Hope this helps you.